# i'm just start with flask. i have any problem on lesson session. (I'm weak in English)

Tags: python-3.x, flask

i'm try practice session lesson with simple session. but it show error TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR3U6.png).
and this my code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCOtS.png). this link i'm practice https://www.javatpoint.com/flask-session.

i just want to show how to fix this error. sorry I'm weak in English

Answer (score 0):

you're making a function called session, but then you're probably trying to add a variable to the session between the client and the server - but these two have the **same name** in your code.

you cannot add a variable to the **function** "session" like you would to a **session object**

you should **rename** your function (your endpoint /session, def session() ) to something else (like /test_session and def testsession() ), and then try again

please, also copy-paste your code and errors into your stackoverflow question as text instead of posting screenshots

Comment: nice, and welcome to stackoverflow! you can accept my answer and give it an upvote if your question is closed.